# Hacer un .exe en QT

Tags: c++, qt

necesito su ayuda, el problema es que hice un pequeño programa grafico en C++ en QT, todo bien, pero al ejecutar el .exe que crea la carpeta debug no lo abre, se supone que el archivo se lo debo mandar a mi maestro por lo que no se que debo hacer para que el .exe funcione en otros equipos adicionales al mio, espero una respuesta :c

Comment: ¿Estan las librerias dll junto con el exe? tal vez sea por eso. Si es asi te tiene que salir un mensaje cuando intentas ejecutarlo de que libreria falta

Comment: Añadi cada .dll que aparecia en la ventanas emergentes, al final aparecio un mensaje de "La aplicacion no se pudo iniciar correctamente (0x000007b)"

Comment: Actualización:
Con el comando windeployqt logre hacer que corriera en mi computadora, pero el problema es si habrá manera de que con solo el .exe pueda abrirse? Así como Code Blocks

Comment: Para que solo pueda correr con el .exe, es que user qt como libreria estatica, yo nunca lo hice asi, para eso creo que tendrias que compilar la libreria qt a travez del codigo

Comment: @ManuelTorres Tienes que hacer un deployment como lo señala la docs: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Answer (score 1):

Las librerías de Qt, por defecto, se enlazan de forma dinámica, esto es, no pasan a formar parte de tu ejecutable sino que se quedan como DLLs. Esto implica que el ejecutable necesita localizar dichas librerías para poder funcionar.

Adicionalmente, es probable que el compilador te obligue a arrastrar alguna librería adicional.

Resumiendo, tienes que coger las librería de Qt utilizadas por tu programa más las dependencias impuestas por el compilador y llevarlas junto a tu ejecutable.

Para más información al respecto, consulta este enlace (Es el mismo que te han indicado vía comentarios)

Comment: Ok gracias, ya lo intente añadiendo los DLL y si funciono, gracias por la infor respecto al compilador.